# RedirectToAction() with tab-id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have a web application in ASP.NET MVC and in there i have a jqueryUI tab with forms in.
And when i submit i want to return to the open tab.

With me RedirectToAction() i create the url

```
www.foo.com/CV/edit/9
```

But i want to be able to generate

```
www.foo.com/CV/edit/9#tab-2
```

I tried with RedirectToAction("edit/"+id+"#tab-2"), but that generates:

```
www.foo.com/CV/edit/9%23tab-2
```

any1 knows the answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create the URL, then append `#tab-2` to it. Return a RedirectResult to redirect to the created URL:

```
return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("edit", new { id }) + "#tab-2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect to a hashed URL because they aren't a physical URL. The hash is used for internal page anchoring. You'd be best off using a URL parameter like `&tab=2`