# Redirect to Page but specific Tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tabs

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725474/redirecttoaction-with-tab-id) as an example of what I am trying to do.

I have a tabbed page.

In my Controller I want to redirect to a page but a specific tab on that page.

Now when I am on that page, and hover over the tab the link is `http://localhost:xxxxx/OInfoes/Details/2#phases`

So in my controller I did this to try and recreate the same link:

```
return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Details", "OInfoes", new { id = phase.OID }) + "#phases");
```

This gives me the correct link but it doesn't put me on the correct tab.

How do I get this to work?

My HTML for the tabs is below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#oInfo" data-toggle="tab">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#reports" data-toggle="tab">Previous Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#phases" data-toggle="tab">Previous/Current Phases</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are generating the link correctly, so there  is probably some additional logic on that page that handles the hash changing when you are on that page and which is different than when you are redirected to that page with the hash on it. What JavaScript library are you using?

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET I am using jQuery, but I haven't done anything with jQuery for this.. these tabs have been generated by [Bootstrap](http://bootswatch.com/default/#navs) markup

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33675057/40521

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should update your action method to take a parameter to represent the tab to be selected.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id,string tab="")
{
   if (id != null)
        ViewBag.ActiveTab = id.ToString();
   // to do : Return a view
}
```

When you return the redirect result, send a querystring with name tab

```
return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Details", "OInfoes", new { id = phase.OID ,
                                                                           tab="phases"}));
```

Now in your document ready, use the value of `ViewBag.ActiveTab` value, generate the jQuery selector from that and use that to call `.tab('show')`.

```
$(function () {
    var selector = '@ViewBag.ActiveTab';
    if(selector)
    {
       $("#link-tab"+selector).tab('show');
    }        
});
```

Make sure your tab's has id's matching with our above code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#oInfo" id="link-info" data-toggle="tab">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#reports" id="link-reports" data-toggle="tab">Prev Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#phases" id="link-phases" data-toggle="tab">Prev/Cur Phases</a></li>
</ul>
```